# why doesn't segmentation fault occur here?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

if I don't define the size of my vector the segmentation fault will occur but in this way , I mean that I define the size lower than the size I use , the segmentation fault won't occur . but why?
what is the difference between them ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    vector <string> a(2);
    a[0]="hello world";
    a[2]="maryam";
    cout << a[0] << a[2];
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You're causing undefined behavior. The behavior in this case is undefined. A segmentation fault is just one possible result of undefined behavior. Your computer could order pizza or format your disk instead. You shouldn't expect anything.

Comment: @ThomasSablik: that's *related* but refers to an actual array rather than a vector. I'll leave it to the swarm to decide if it's an *actual* dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ has a notion of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Accessing a vector out-of-bounds is a typical example of undefined behavior (because [`vector::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) performs no bounds checking). Nothing meaningful can be said about the outcome of the program.

But to explain what *probably* happens...

A `vector` is a `class` that usually contains a *pointer* to a heap-allocated array and its *size* (the "*capacity*").

An empty vector has a null pointer value. Dereferencing a null pointer often *immediately* leads to a segfault because there's no virtual memory region allocated at address 0.

On the other hand, a vector of capacity `2` points to an array of size `2`. Writing past it is often possible, you will simply overwrite heap memory that happens to reside immediately *after* that array. This is called a [*heap buffer overflow*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_overflow). In a simple program it may appear to work fine. But in a larger program nothing good will happen somewhere further down the code.

Answer (score 1):

Undefined behaviour (which is what you're doing when reading or writing beyond the end of a vector with `operator[]`) is *exactly* that, undefined.

It could just as easily crash for the size two case and seem to work for size zero.

Or both could format your storage devices while playing `maniacal_laughter.mp3`.

Undefined behaviour places *no* limits on the outcome, and it's something you would be well advised to steer clear of.

Answer (score 1):

[] operator does not have range check. [] operator is used for directly accessing a memory address based on the offset value and "base" address.
From your example,

```
a[0], a[2]
```

0 and 2 are offset values, and "base" address will be the address of the array, pointed by the vector.
If you want to have range check, use:

```
a.at(0), a.at(2)
```